# Prepared PDO MySQL statement commits but changes do not stick

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am having a problem where a prepared MySQL stored procedure call runs fine in a transaction, and I see the expected results from the stored procedure, but the changes do not appear to be saving to the actual database.

The PHP side of things looks like this:

```
$options = array();
$db = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mydb", "myuser", "mypass", $options);
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);

// ..... .... ... .. .

$response["error"] = true;
if ($db->beginTransaction() == true)
{
    try
    {
        $stmt = $db->prepare("call Layout_Row_Add(:pageid, :position);");
        // $jason->page_id
        $stmt->bindValue(':pageid', (int)$jason->page_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        // $jason->position
        $stmt->bindValue(':position', (int)$jason->position, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->execute();
        $response["dbg1"] = $jason->page_id;
        $response["dbg2"] = $jason->position;
        $response["intrans1"] = $db->inTransaction();
        $row = $stmt->fetch();
        $db->commit();
        $response["intrans2"] = $db->inTransaction();           
        $response["new_row_id"] = $row["NewRowId"];
        $response["error"] = false;
    }
    catch (PDOException $e)
    {
        $db->rollBack();
        $response["errortext"] = "PDO exception: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
    catch (Exception $exc)
    {
        $db->rollBack();
        $response["errortext"] = "Exception: " . $e->getMessage();
    }       
}
else            
{
    $response["errortext"] = "Couldn't start transaction";
}
```

The `$response` variable gets encoded into JSON and sent back to the browser, which gets this:

```
error       false
dbg1        1
dbg2        3
intrans1    true
intrans2    false
new_row_id  21
```

Everything looks exactly like it should, `new_row_id` is at its expected value meaning the autoincrement field ticked up, and the debug fields and transaction info is as expected.

However, doing a select * in MySQL Workbench doesn't return any of these rows that were supposedly added by the procedure. Running the procedure itself in MySQL Workbench works fine, as in, the commit actually sticks. Here's the procedure itself:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`myuser`@`myhost` PROCEDURE `Layout_Row_Add`(PageId int, Position int)
BEGIN
    declare NewRowId int unsigned default 0;
    update pages_layout_rows set ordinal = ordinal + 1 where page_id = PageId and ordinal >= Position;
    insert into pages_layout_rows (page_id, ordinal) values (PageId, Position);
    set NewRowId = last_insert_id();
    select NewRowId; 
END
```

The table is set to InnoDB, so transaction support should be available. I don't really know what to try next.

Comment: Why use stored procedures? Worst case scenario can you put the queries into PHP instead?

Comment: Also, move `$row = $stmt->fetch();` after `$db->commit();` and see what you're getting outside the transaction.

Comment: Moving the fetch had no effect. Hardcoding the statements makes the update work, but I prefer to use stored procedures mostly for encapsulation.

Answer (score 0):

Found it - it looks like if you don't consume all the resultsets, the transaction appears to get rolled back in the end anyway. A stored procedure call adds an empty resultset as the last resultset, so that's what's happening.

```
// ...
$row = $stmt->fetch();
// let's consume all resultsets
while($stmt->nextRowset() && $stmt->columnCount());
$sol->db->commit();
// ...
```